# Why does $.ajaxSetup not work with $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why does this code post the sessionID parameter

```
    $.post("ajax/p_getOnePosition.jsp", {
        positionNo: positionNo,
        sessionID: v_sessionID,
    }, function(response2) {
```

But not this code

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        sessionID: v_sessionID,
    });
    
    $.post("ajax/p_getOnePosition.jsp", {
        positionNo: positionNo,
    }, function(response2) {
```

Comment: What is `v_sessionID` and when is it set?  After `$.ajaxSetup` called?

Comment: It is a security token. It is set before $.ajaxSetup is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `beforeSend` instead as follows.  Code inspired from [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-setup-not-working-for-post-request)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        settings.data += "&sessionID="+v_sessionID;
  }
});

$.post("ajax/p_getOnePosition.jsp", {
    positionNo: positionNo,
}, function(response2) {
```