# Why does beforeSend in $ajaxSetup not add parameters to a parameter-less function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am attempting to add a security token to all my AJAX $.post calls.

I set up the security token to be automatically added using the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617103/why-does-ajaxsetup-not-work-with-post/65617104#65617104)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        settings.data += "&sessionID="+v_sessionID;
  }
});
```

and then code such as the following, will have the security token automatically appended

```
$.post("ajax/p_getOnePosition.jsp", {
    positionNo: positionNo,
}, function(response2) {
```

The code works well, but not for functions with no parameters such as

```
$.post("ajax/p_clearFilters.jsp", {

}, function(response2) {
```

Any idea why this should be?

I can fix it by simply adding a dummy parameter `dummy:1` to the code

```
 $.post("ajax/p_clearFilters.jsp", {
       dummy:1
    }, function(response2) {
```

So I tried to do

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
     beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        var noParameters=(settings.data==null || settings.data==undefined || settings.data=='');
        settings.data += (noParameters?"dummy=1":"") +"&sessionID="+v_sessionID;
  }
});
```

but this did not mimic having the `dummy=1` manually added, and the security token was not available in the request.

**UPDATE**

I realize in retrospect (after @Rory McCrossan's comment and @Louys Patrice Bessette's answer) that my question was incomplete.  I should have also included in my question the JSP code that I use to retrieve the parameter.

```
<%
String csrfSessionID = SecurityIssues.StringToAlphaNumericStr(request.getParameter("sessionID"));
%>
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/5ng8kohm/. If you check the request in the network tab of the console you'll see the `&sessionId` value in the request payload. ***However*** the leading `&` on the key in that case could possibly be causing an issue in your server side. Try improving the logic so the `&` is only added when necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much @RoryMcCrossan for taking the time to try and replicate the issue. From running your code I see - as you write - that the sessionId value is in the "Request Payload". But when the //positionNo:1 is uncommented then both the PositionNo and the sessionId value are displayed as "Form Data". And it seems I am only able to retrieve successfully the data from "Form Data" and not "Request Payload". Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Also I did attempt to deal with the leading `&` in the code at the end of my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working through @Rory McCrossan's comment and @Louys Patrice Bessette's answer - thank you very much - I see that when beforeSend adds to an empty parameter list, then the SESSIONID is sent as part of the Request Payload, and when beforeSend adds to pre-existing parameter list, then SESSIONID is sent as part of the Form Data. This makes a difference in retrieving the parameters.

For data as part of the Form Data then it can be retrieved by the following:

```
String csrfSessionID = SecurityIssues.StringToAlphaNumericStr(request.getParameter("sessionID"));
```

For data as part of the request Payload it can be retrieved by the following:
See @Fizer Khan's answer in [Getting request payload from POST request in Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet)

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
java.io.BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line);
    buffer.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
String data = buffer.toString();
System.out.println("data:"+data);
```

These two code snippets are **mutually exclusive**. The first code cannot retrieve from the Request Payload, and the second code cannot retrieve from the Form Data

Note that probably a better answer would force the beforeSend to send the SessionID in the Form Data in all cases, but this is a good workaround for now!

Answer (score 1):

You have three `data` cases:

- undefined
- empty
- not empty

Try that `beforeSend` function:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
    
    // Undefined data
    settings.data = settings.data === undefined ? "" : settings.data;

    // Add the & or not in front of the sessionID
    settings.data +=
      (settings.data.length > 0 ? "&" : "") + "sessionID=SESSION_ID";
    console.log("before send:", settings.data);
    
  }
});
```

The below snippet always ends up in an error because the request url is https://example.com. ;)

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
    
    // Undefined data
    settings.data = settings.data === undefined ? "" : settings.data;

    // Add the & or not in front of the sessionID
    settings.data +=
      (settings.data.length > 0 ? "&" : "") + "sessionID=SESSION_ID";
    console.log("before send:", settings.data);
    
  }
});

$(".test").on("submit", function (e) {
  console.clear();
  e.preventDefault();

  let formId = $(this)[0].id;
  console.log( `You are trying the ${formId}`);

  let formValues;
  switch (formId) {
    
    case "test_1":
      // Do not set formValues on purpose...
      break;
    
    case "test_2":
      formValues = {};
      break;

    case "test_3":
      formValues = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doh" };
      break;

  }

  console.log("on submit:", formValues);

  $.post("https://example.com", formValues)
    .done(function () {
      console.log("DONE");
    })
    .fail(function () {
      console.error("ERROR - (obviously!) - Check the Network tab-> example.com -> Headers -> Form Data");
    });
});
```

```css
button{
  margin: 1em;
  width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="test" id="test_1">
  <button>Test #1 - Send an undefined object</button>
</form>

<form class="test" id="test_2">
  <button>Test #2 - Send an empty object</button>
</form>

<form class="test" id="test_3">
  <button>Test #3 - Send an object</button>
</form>
```

Also on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qBaMZzN?editors=0011)

Comment: Thank you very much for your long and detailed and helpful answer. After working through it, it led me to finding the problem. I updated my question a bit because I realize in retrospect it could have been more complete. Appreciated!